# Swift Parsing with Json

Tags: json, swift, parsing

I'm trying to parsing Json using swift and this is the json I get

```
{"Data":{"KanBan":[{"Sdate":"2020/06/22","Stype":"上班卡","Stime":"09:31:11","Ip":"xxx.xxx.xxx.xx"},{"Sdate":"2020/06/20","Stype":"下班卡","Stime":"20:53:43","Ip":"xxx.xxx.xxx.xx"},{"Sdate":"2020/06/20","Stype":"下班卡","Stime":"20:48:25","Ip":"xxx.xxx.xxx.xx"},{"Sdate":"2020/06/20","Stype":"下班卡","Stime":"18:53:57","Ip":"xxx.xxx.xxx.xx"},{"Sdate":"2020/06/20","Stype":"上班卡","Stime":"18:43:54","Ip":"xxx.xxx.xxx.xx  "}]},"IsSuccess":true,"Message":null,"ErrorCode":null,"ErrorMessage":null}
```

Below is the struct I defined and use it with Swift JsonDecoder :

```
// inside viewController
let decoder = JSONDecoder()

let historys = try decoder.decode([Datas].self, from: data)




// struct I defined myself
struct Datas : Codable {
    
    let Data: KanBan
    let IsSuccess: Bool
    let Message: String
    let ErrorCode: String
    let ErrorMessage: String
    
    init( Data: KanBan, IsSuccess: Bool, Message: String, ErrorCode: String, ErrorMessage: String) {
        self.Data = Data
        self.IsSuccess = IsSuccess
        self.Message = Message
        self.ErrorCode = ErrorCode
        self.ErrorMessage = ErrorMessage
    }
}


struct KanBan : Codable {

    let KanBan: [details]
    init( kanbans : [details]) {
        self.KanBan = kanbans
    }
}



struct details: Codable {

    let Sdate: Date
    let Stype: String
    let Stime : String
    let Ip: String
    
    init(Sdate: Date, Stype: String, Stime : String, Ip: String ) {
        self.Sdate = Sdate
        self.Stype = Stype
        self.Stime = Stime
        self.Ip = Ip
    }
}
```

I keep get error that said parsing failed .
Whats wrong with the struct I defined ? Plz help and thanks!!!

Comment: "error that said parsing failed" What error? How did you print the error? From what I'm seeing, [Datas].self should be Datas.self because top level isn't an array. And that's only the first of many mistakes (optional values, dates behavior?) etc. But first: print and read the error.

Comment: @Larme    Thaks for the reply.    I didn't print out the error but i should !!     And yes! I misunderstand usage of [Datas] .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fix 3 things:

1. You're trying to decode `[Datas]` whereas it should be `Datas`.
2. If the keys are optional you should declare them as optional. eg: ErrorMessage, ErrorCode.
3. Provide the DateFormatter if you're trying to decode Dates.

Here's the code you need: -

Model:

```
struct Datas: Codable {
    let Data: KanBan
    let IsSuccess: Bool
    let Message: String?
    let ErrorCode: String?
    let ErrorMessage: String?
}

struct KanBan: Codable {
    let KanBan: [details]
}

struct details: Codable {
    let Sdate: Date
    let Stype: String
    let Stime : String
    let Ip: String
}
```

Decoding:

```
do {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd"
    decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(dateFormatter)
    let historys = try decoder.decode(Datas.self, from: data)
    print(historys)
} catch { print(error) }
```